# REST Access Project Information from Different Server PHP

Tags: php, rest, jira

I am able to access my company's dashboards from JIRA's REST api by calling:

```
<pre>
<?php
    $array = file('https://jira.COMPANYNAME.com/rest/api/2/dashboard');
    $api = json_decode($array[0], true);
    print_r($api['dashboards']);
?>
<pre>
```

This shows me a nice list of our dashboards and their relevant data.  However, when I try to call it as /rest/api/2/project, it returns '[]' to my web page whereas in my browser I have a complete list.  Attempting to go deeper (by requesting to look in a specific project ID) returns a 404 error to the server.

I am aware JIRA is able to tell that my browser is logged in whereas the server making the request is not.  However, I can not for the life of me figure out how to grant access to my server.  All I require is that the server is allowed to do:

```
<?php
    $array = file('https://jira.COMPANYNAME.com/rest/api/2/project');
?>
```

A user account can be hard-coded in for this, as my company wishes to use a dummy account that can look at all projects, even those that a given employee personally does not have access to.  If it needs to scale up eventually we can do that, but it will only work if we can access the tools in the first place.

Comment: so get a user/pass issued for your php script, then have it replicate the login sequence so it can get whatever auth token is required (e.g. cookie)... basically replicate in php/curl whatever you're doing in your browser to log in.

Comment: What do you get if you don't drill down into the array? As in... print_r($array)

Comment: I may be wrong...but would we use something like curl and post a username and password?

Comment: Maybe I should mention, I'm also a bit new to programming.  I'm currently here as a summer job in college, so I'm still pretty new to things such as GET and POST, since my curriculum thus far has been with C, C++, and assembly.  I really have no idea how to correctly send a POST to JIRA which contains a username and password, although that's what I've been attempting the last day and a half.

Comment: @Pete Simmons Without drilling down, the dashboard gives me everything on a single line.  Drilling is really just to improve the readability of the information.  Not drilling the Projects however is still just '[]', since I'm pretty sure JIRA is returning nothing as a security feature.

Comment: I would have a look into the Guzzle framework for consuming REST data. http://guzzle.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ the examples should get you on your way in terms of sending the correct headers easily. Takes the headache out of a lot of it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use BASIC authentication like in this tutorial: https://developer.atlassian.com/jiradev/jira-apis/jira-rest-apis/jira-rest-api-tutorials/jira-rest-api-example-basic-authentication